# Arc length of the curve $x^1=2a\cos t$, $x^2=sint$.

Tags: polar-coordinates, tensors, arc-length

Using the metric Euclidean tensor for polar coordinates,
calculate the arc length for the curve:

$x^1=2a\cos t$

$x^2=\sin t$ where $0\leq t\leq2\pi$

If I use the formula:

$L=\int_{a} ^{b} \sqrt{\left(\cfrac{dx^1} {dt} \right)^2+\left(\cfrac{dx^2} {dt}\right) ^2}=\sqrt{\left| \delta_{ij} \cfrac{dx^1} {dt}\cfrac{dx^2} {dt}\right|}  $

I get  an elliptic integral, can anyone help me to find the arc lenght? and How could you interpret the result geometrically?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: is $a$ a paramater ? I mean, is $x_1=2\arccos(t)$ or $x_1=2a\cos(t)$ ?

Comment: Yes it is a real parameter. $x_1=2acos(t)$ @Surb

Comment: Then use the latex command \cos for the cosinus. Your integrale has no closed form. You can't do better than what you have.

Comment: You say "polar coordinates", but it don't seem you used them

Comment: $L$ is indeed obtained via a complete elliptic integral of the second kind and the geometric interpretation is... the *length* (!) What more do you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably noticed, the result is
$$L=2 \left(E\left(-4 a^2\right)+\sqrt{4 a^2+1} E\left(\frac{4 a^2}{4
   a^2+1}\right)\right)$$ What you can do is to approximate $L$ using $[2n,2n]$ Padé approximants built around $a=0$.

For example
$$P_2=2\pi\, \frac {1+\frac{159 }{44}a^2+\frac{453 }{176}a^4 } { 1+\frac{115 }{44}a^2+\frac{125 }{176}a^4}$$
$$P_3=2\pi\, \frac {1+\frac{39575 }{7116}a^2+\frac{20621}{2372}a^4+\frac{129235
   }{37952}a^6} {1+\frac{32459 }{7116}a^2+\frac{34741 }{7116}a^4+\frac{79037
   }{113856}a^6 } $$
$$P_4=2\pi\, \frac {1+\frac{133542997 }{17725732}a^2+\frac{1325913585 }{70902928}a^4+\frac{1210596065
  }{70902928}a^6+\frac{4808786003 }{1134446848}a^8 } {1+\frac{115817265 }{17725732}a^2+\frac{915821721 }{70902928}a^4+\frac{553597479
   }{70902928}a^6+\frac{777708891 }{1134446848}a^8 }$$

The table shows how good (or bad) are these approximations
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
a & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & \text{exact} \\
 0.00 & 6.283185307 & 6.283185307 & 6.283185307 & 6.283185307 \\
 0.25 & 6.659164725 & 6.659167214 & 6.659167222 & 6.659167222 \\
 0.50 & 7.639438651 & 7.640368153 & 7.640394783 & 7.640395578 \\
 0.75 & 8.969481052 & 8.985328348 & 8.986601081 & 8.986713343 \\
 1.00 & 10.44445389 & 10.52687833 & 10.53873159 & 10.54073433 \\
 1.25 & 11.91631116 & 12.15523595 & 12.20520464 & 12.21838971 \\
 1.50 & 13.29114874 & 13.78900721 & 13.92449946 & 13.97441783 \\
 1.75 & 14.52204955 & 15.36792068 & 15.64828398 & 15.78301361 \\
 2.00 & 15.59531652 & 16.85165250 & 17.33739745 & 17.62855113 
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

To better see the gain, consider the norm
$$\Phi_n=\int^2_0 \big[L-P_n\big]^2\,da$$ which leads to $$\Phi_2=0.983 \qquad \Phi_3=0.114 \qquad \Phi_4=0.013$$ that is to say almost a factor of $10$ when $n \to n+1$.